# Class-internal Protocols in Swift

Tags: swift, scope, swift-protocols

How can I implement class-internal protocols in Swift?

The problem is that

```
class C {
    private protocol P {
        func aFunction()
    }

    private class D: P {
        func aFunction() {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

results in the error

> Declaration is only valid at file scope

Any ideas for bypassing the problem?

*Exclusion: I do **not** refer to [class-only protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID281), which is possible, of course.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access control in swift is file based. I do not believe you can define a protocol within a class, but you can include it within the same document.

```
private protocol P {
    func aFunction()
}

class C {
    private class D: P {
        private func aFunction() {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this does not mean that classes that inherit from class `C` can use protocol `P`.

To my knowledge Swift does not support inheritance based access control.